# How to add multiple string values in a single Text View item

Tags: java, android-studio

I am developing an android application where users will be able to select some numbers or a single seat from a seating plan. And when the seat is changing the color and a user can choose more than one seat, and i wanted to set those seats' names to a certain text view, so i would like to know how to set those multiple names of seats to a text view when the seat image button is clicked

Here is the code,

```
 mH01 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.H01);
        mH01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mH01.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
// I want to set  a seat name to a text View here
            }
        });
mH02 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.H01);
        mH01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mH02.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

//and when this seat is clicked its name should also be set to a same text view and should be separated with comma sign
            }
        });
```

Comment: `textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + ", " + "seat name here");`

Answer (score 3):

For several text items you can use string concatenation or `String.format()`
    textView.setText(String.format("%s, seat name here", textView.getText().toString())

But in case you need to concat a lot of strings you should use `StringBuilder()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
yourtextView.setText(yourtextView.getText().toString() + ", " + "your seatname");
```